# Constellations Puzzle : Find The Hidden Message

Tags: logical-deduction, pattern

Find the hidden message in the first three constellations based on the clues provided by the others.

[image]

Comment: I am guessing that each bezier control point represents a letter, so the first (red) message is a 4 letter word that might start with s.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! Is this from an ongoing contest?

Comment: Is that your signature in the bottom right corner? If so, can you edit your post to make that clearer? I apologize for the deletion earlier - it seemed to be from an ongoing competition, and those puzzles are banned here.

Comment: Yes its my signature for puzzle..is it possible to enable same post .

Comment: This neat puzzle would probably have more than 27 views and 2 votes (good ratio, by the way) after 3 days if the solution had been given 24 hours before being checked off. (Oh, and without spending time as deleted too.) Wish this would get more attention as a good example of presentation and clues.

Comment: @humn You could always draw attention to it with a small bounty ;)

Comment: Good one, @Will, forgot how aptly named "has not received anough attention" is. On its way, though we still can't award bounties to questions.

Comment: I am not sure whether that's intentional, but [Milky Way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milky_Way) is spelled like that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Constellations read:

> SAVE EARTH MOTHER (Thanks @Wen)

Which logically rearranges to:

> SAVE MOTHER EARTH

The trick:

> Each 'turning point' of a curve is assigned a letter. Specific locations within the square have letters assigned. I'm just having trouble working out where that center curve actually goes to, as the curves don't always quite reach the same turning point, it just seems to be general locale that is assigned to a letter.

Answer (score 10):

Humankind has received a
[subliminal message](http://rationalwiki.org/wiki/Subliminal_messages)
to . . .

> . . . S A V E  
>  [E A R T H   M O T H E R](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/earth_mother)
>  . . .

. . . and to illustrate
[TheGreatEscaper’s solution](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/47462/18129).

> [image]

This puzzle is so neatly presented and solidly clued, it really doesn’t
require more explanation.

So our crackerjack graphologists had time to authenticate the signature.

> [image]

Gotta love the cosmic imagery
and — conscientious
as well — messagery.

The secret message states the truly difficult puzzle.

Comment: @humn ..awesome solve

Comment: Thank you for an attractive opportunity, @Dharmesh! (I Also suspect that your actual template resembles a spiral galaxy even more than shown here.)